# Wrap.builder implementation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to implement `Wrap.builder` to make the widget tree build only widgets that are on-screen, not all of the children at once like `ListView.builder` does?

#### Example

```dart
final myList= List.Generate(25,(i)=>'index: ${i+1}');
Wrap.builder(
    itemCount: myList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,i) => Text(myList[i]),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Wrap` does not do that, only Sliver-based widgets can render stuff on the fly. If performance is not an issue, do not over-optimize and continue to use stuff such as `Wrap` or `Column`. If you have identified a real performance issue, consider switching to slivers - such as `ListView` or other slivers.

Comment: This is not necessarily over-optimization. The use case could be to display a few seconds an information when the component is built and disappear after. If the component is no on the screen you loose the bahavior of the build.